Name for group of buttons that move values up/down or inc/decrement
Many devices have buttons that change the state of the world by inc/decrementing a value or going to the next/previous value. Examples such as

tv remote volume up/down
air con temp up/down
car engine mode select next/prev (eg. eco, normal, perf)

Is there a dedicated word or way to reference buttons with this behavior, that is perhaps more specific than just "buttons", "controls", "the up/down ..." or similar?

Volume control, channel control, temperature control, etc. Some UI toolkits define a Buttonset but that's not a standard English term.

Thanks @StuartF, I was looking for a generic description that doesn't mention the property they're changing

raise/lower the temperature [increment/ decrement are wrong here]. Each type of control is preceded by the function.

The physical devices that such GUI elements emulate are called momentary rocker switches. The modifier momentary specifies that the switch is spring-loaded and returns to its default middle position when the user releases pressure on either of its ends. It might be used, for instance to adjust the exact height (position) of a motor-driven roller shade.
A regular rocker switch stays in whichever of its two positions the user has set it to until it is next moved to the other position. This kind of rocker is typically found, for instance, as the power switch (labeled “1” and “0”) at the back of an electric appliance.

An everyday term for such things in the physical world is knob.
Search Google images for "stereo knob"  (just to eliminate cabinet knobs) even though these devices appear on many different kinds of equipment, like radios, TV, analog home-heating/cooling thermostats, laboratory devices, etc.
You could call them "knob controls".
There are two kinds: infinite adjustment and stepped adjustment. Stepped adjustment knobs have detents that give a tactile feedback with each incremental move up or down; infinite adjustment knobs turn smoothly and permit finer-grained adjustment.

A knob isn't a button.

@NuclearHoagie  What the OP described isn't necessarily a button.  The A/C temp in my car is conrtrolled by a twist knob, as is the car engine mode in many vehicles.  If the OP is thinking of up/down arrow buttons, they're arrow buttons.
